# sqlalchemy protection against sql injections- using engine.execute() api

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sql-injection

I tried to find a method for using sqlalchemy's `engine.execute` level solutions for sql injections, but I came across this is possible via ORM style.

How can we achieve it using engine-level api?

Comment: Can you include an example of what you are trying or hypothetically worried about?  Pretty sure multiple techniques are explained in docs from placeholders in `text()` to core to ORM.

Comment: @IanWilson: I'm dealing with legacy code having a string of sql query template with placeholders, in which we can have sql injected codes.  

for example: `select * from foo1 where id ='drop table foo2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bind parameters with [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) to avoid SQL injection.  Also using the sql/core layer to build queries should also work of course, ie. session.execute(select(my_table).where(id=some_id)).

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me the differences between select literals and the text option above?

Comment: JavaSa, `text()`, let's you write SQL the long hand way as plain text, like `session.execute(text("SELECT * FROM foo1 WHERE id = :my_id"), my_id=15)` whereas using `select` you can programmatically build SQL like, `session.execute(select(foo1_table_obj).where(foo1_table_obj.c.my_id == 15))`.   You should start with the tutorial at [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html) .